# iterate through objects javascript with Int index

Tags: javascript, loops, object

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object}
    0:Object
        0: "aaa"
        1: "bbb"
    1:Object
        0: "ccc"
        1: "ddd"



for (i in mainobject){
            for (l in i){

                        console.log("l is: "+ l["1"]);

            }
}
```

How i get "ddd" in javascript, the loop i have only return index or undefined?

Comment: Using integer for Object keys is terrible practice - don't use it! Either use array or use string for keys!

Comment: it's object thorugh objects not arrays.

Comment: when you use a for...in loop be sure to use the var keyword otherwise you are making your variable i a global variable. e.g. for (var i in mainobject){..}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for..in` loops in javascript put the KEY into the iterator variable you create, not the value.  Try this:

```
for (var i in mainObject) {
    var item = mainObject[i];
}
```

If each of these objects is a nested object you want to inspect, do so:

```
for (var i in mainObject) {
    var item = mainObject[i];
    for (var j in item) {
        console.log(item[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That i you get gives you the index rather than the nested object. You need to adjust your second for loop.

```
for(var i in mainobject) {
   var secondobject = mainobject[i];
   for(var l in secondobject) {
      console.log("l is: "+ secondobject[l]);
   };
};
```